# 1046 error for symbol added to stage in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, compiler-errors

The error I keep getting is this x4:

```
Symbol 'list'  ---  1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant
```

I have four movie clips within my movie clip named 'list', which are called print1, etc. I get an error for each one. All I'm trying to do is add the 'list' movieclip to the stage with addChild(list), which worked before I added those four 'print' movieclips.

The 'print' movieclips are nested within a folder and subfolder in my library. My 'list' symbol is in the main directory. Would that have any influence on the error? Or do I have to declare anything else besides the 'list' movieclip in the actionscript?

Comment: Have u ensured the linkage id enabled for action script for that symbol is `list`? Also if you have `list.as` class where have u put it? either in the main directory(where .fla and .swf resides) or in the subfolders? Give some info about that it could be helpful to help u.

Comment: Also, Actionscript is case sensitive, so if your class or library asset is named `List`, you should use correct casing.

Comment: Like I said above, the symbol only stopped working when I changed what was IN the symbol. I already linked the symbol with `"list:MyList = new MyList"`, and it was fine when I simply had a rectangle in the symbol's timeline to test it. Everything else in my class works.

And when I said subfolders, I meant folders within the library, not the project folder itself.

Comment: When you say you have 4 mc's named 'list', do you mean their instance names or their AS linkage class names?  Either way, you can't use the same name (instance or class) for multiple elements.

Comment: No, my main mc is named 'list'. The ones within list are instantiated as print1, print2, print3, and print4.

Comment: Any code in the print mc themselves?

Answer (score 0):

You need to either have "declare stage instances automatically" checked, or you need to provide a variable in the Class definition.